# Why doesn't communication between an EFR32FG14 and a SI7021 using I2C work?

Tags: embedded

I have tried to follow the I2C diagram of Si7021 below step by step.

From the starter kit manual my SDA and SCL is P13 and P12 on my board respectively, which is location 15 in the datasheet page 150 table shown below.

I have been writing and reading exactly by the registers in the reference manual shown below. I have tested if one step is accomplished before going to the next step as shown in the code below. Every line has a comment regarding which step it is in the I2C diagram.

The real connection is shown below. I am sending this whole procedure over and over in a while(1) loop, and I get only noise, no digital behavior at all on my scope.

Where did I go wrong?

[EFR32FG14 Starter Kit Manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/ug318-brd4257b-user-guide.pdf)

[Si7021 Sensor Page 20](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf%20Efr32fg14%20reference%20manual)

[EFR32FG14 Reference Manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf)

[EFR32FG14 Data Sheet Page 150](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efr32fg14-datasheet.pdf)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_i2c.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "bsp.h"


// Buffers
uint8_t i2c_txBuffer[] = "Gecko";
uint8_t i2c_txBufferSize = sizeof(i2c_txBuffer);
uint8_t MS_Byte;
uint8_t LS_Byte;
uint8_t checksum;
int flag_2nd_step=0;
int flag_3rd_step=0;

/**************************************************************************//**
* @brief  Starting oscillators and enabling clocks
*****************************************************************************/
void initCMU(void)
{
  // Enabling clock to the I2C, GPIO, LE
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_I2C0, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_HFLE, true);

  // Starting LFXO and waiting until it is stable
  CMU_OscillatorEnable(cmuOsc_LFXO, true, true);
}



/**************************************************************************//**
* @brief  Setup I2C
*****************************************************************************/
void initI2C(void)
{
  // Using default settings
  I2C_Init_TypeDef i2cInit = I2C_INIT_DEFAULT;
  // Use ~400khz SCK
  i2cInit.freq = I2C_FREQ_FAST_MAX;

  // Using PC10 (SDA) and PC11 (SCL)
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 10, gpioModeWiredAndPullUp, 1);
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 11, gpioModeWiredAndPullUp, 1);

  //Si7021 switch on
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortD, 15, gpioModePushPull, 1);

  // Enable pins at location 15 as specified in datasheet
  I2C0->ROUTEPEN = I2C_ROUTEPEN_SDAPEN | I2C_ROUTEPEN_SCLPEN;
  I2C0->ROUTELOC0 = (I2C0->ROUTELOC0 & (~_I2C_ROUTELOC0_SDALOC_MASK)) | I2C_ROUTELOC0_SDALOC_LOC15;
  I2C0->ROUTELOC0 = (I2C0->ROUTELOC0 & (~_I2C_ROUTELOC0_SCLLOC_MASK)) | I2C_ROUTELOC0_SCLLOC_LOC15;

  // Initializing the I2C
  I2C_Init(I2C0, &i2cInit);


  }



int main(void)
{
  // Chip errata
  CHIP_Init();

  // Configuring clocks in the Clock Management Unit (CMU)
  initCMU();



  // Setting up i2c
  initI2C();
while(1)
{
  I2C0->CMD=I2C0->CMD|(1<<0); //step 1 start CMD

  I2C0->TXDATA=((I2C0->TXDATA)&(0xFF00))|(0x80); //step 2 sending sensor address with 0 write bit
  while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<4))!=1){}//wait till command transfer ends TXBL flag

  if (((I2C0->IF)&(1<<6))==1)//if we recieve ACK send measure and read command //3rd step
        {
           I2C0->TXDATA=((I2C0->TXDATA)&(0xFF00))|(0xE3); //step 4 in diagram
           while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<4))!=1){}//wait till command transfer ends TXBL flag


              if (((I2C0->IF)&(1<<6))==1)//if we recieve ACK after Measure CMD
              {
                 flag_2nd_step=1;
              }
        }

  else                       //if we recieve NACK  we send the previos command again
  {
      I2C0->TXDATA=((I2C0->TXDATA)&(0xFF00))|(0x80); //step 2 sending sensor adress with 0 write bit
      while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<4))!=1){}//wait till command transfer ends TXBL flag
      flag_2nd_step=0;
  }

  if (flag_2nd_step==1) //step 3 second slave adress sending
  {
      I2C0->CMD=I2C0->CMD|(1<<0); //step 5 start CMD
      I2C0->TXDATA=((I2C0->TXDATA)&(0xFF00))|(0x81); //step 6 sending sensor adress with 1 read bit
      while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<4))!=1){}//wait till command transfer ends TXBL flag
      flag_3rd_step=1;
  }

  if (flag_3rd_step==1)
    {
      while (((I2C0->IF)&(1<<11))==1){} // step 7 while bushold flag in high and We still in clock streching
    MS_Byte=I2C0->RXDATA; //step 8
    while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<5))==1){}//wait till recieving is complete RXDATAV will turn to 0
    I2C0->CMD=I2C0->CMD|(1<<2); //send ACK to SLAVE
    LS_Byte=I2C0->RXDATA; //step 9
    while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<5))==1){}//wait till recieving is complete RXDATAV will turn to 0
    I2C0->CMD=I2C0->CMD|(1<<2); //send ACK to SLAVE
    checksum=I2C0->RXDATA;//recieve Checksum byte
    I2C0->CMD=I2C0->CMD|(1<<3); //send NACK to SLAVE
    I2C0->CMD=I2C0->CMD|(1<<1); //send STOP to SLAVE
    }//end step 3 end


}//end while
}//end main
```

Comment: Do you have any example code you can just modify to work? It looks like it might be easier than to try finding and fixing all the problems in your current code. For instance, don't you need to wait for some flag to know start condition is properly sent before sending address byte, as that's how many other MCUs work? Also you have multiple basic issues, like comparing variable&(1<<5) with 1, result will never be 1 so code is never run.

Comment: Hello just me, i have written in a comment the logic.It will wait for the recieving to complete and clear this flag to be 0.
Why it will never be 1?
Thanks.

while(((I2C0->IF)&(1<<5))==1){}//wait till recieving is complete RXDATAV will turn to 0

Comment: For example 1<<5 is 0x20. Anything anded with 0x20 will never ever match 1, it is either 0x20 or 0. For how the peripheral works, I don't know, it is just suspicious that you send start and immediately without waiting for start to complete you write the data register, it is possible it works like that, but you need to be sure.

Comment: Hello Justme,i understand my error it will never be 1,if checks if its zero or not zero,if its not zero then we assume that we have 1 on the 5th place.I will rewrite my code.

Comment: Hello Justme,i have updated the code with your remark regarding bitfield checking.i could not paste it all in a comment so i uploaded to alink shown bellow.
Could you please what other things you saw which are problematic?
Thanks.

https://textuploader.com/1excd

Comment: I have never used any EFR32 chip, I opened the reference manual two minutes ago, and noticed you are not doing the I2C based on reference manual suggestions, so I can't really help you. If you don't do it like the manual says, you must have a good reason and enough knowledge to do it in your own way.

Comment: Hello Justme,i have quated in my original post every step from the reference manual and starter kit, and added comments based on them,as you can see in the original post and even shown printscreens.
You are corrent that maybe i missed something.could you tell me ?
I followed stricktly by the protocol

Answer (score 0):

Every line of code that checks the flag bits are incorrect, so the comparisons never work.

The result of a logical AND with, say a value of 0x20, will never be 1, it will be 0x20 or 0, so comparing the result to be equal to 1 will always be false, and comparing the result to be not equal to one will always be true.

In addition, the code does not follow Reference Manual suggestions how to use the I2C peripheral.